# Simple regex that matches x or x+y

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate an input field to accept x OR x+y where x and y are whole numbers from 1-10. Which regular expression matches this? This is to be used with custom jQuery validation.

Examples

- 4: OK
- 5+1: OK
- 0: Not OK
- 0-9: Not OK
- 1+11: Not OK

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it (assuming your "1-10" was inclusive of both ends):

```
^([1-9]|10)(\+([1-9]|10))?$
```

http://rentzsch.github.com/JSRegexTeststand/ is your friend here.

Comment: That was fast ... I was still struggling for 4 more minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the trick

```
/^([1-9]|10)(\+([1-9]|10)){0,1}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    /^([1-9]||10){1}(+([1-9]|10)){0,1}$/

Excellent reference site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html